# Update the database with codeigniter and display the updation in same page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database, codeigniter

I am trying to update the data to the database by php CodeIgniter and display the result in the same page during update. Below is my code.The problem is it didn't show any error message and didn't update the values in the database and It is not displaying any values in the page after update. Please help.
 View Page

```
<?php 
  echo form_open('Welcome/service1'); 
?> 

<input type="hidden" name="servicer_id" value="<?php echo $value['service_id']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="servicer_name" value="<?php echo $value['servicer_name']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="servicer_email" value="<?php echo $value['servicer_email']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="servicer_checkin" value="<?php echo $value['servicer_checkin']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="servicer_checkout" value="<?php echo $value['servicer_checkout']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="servicer_requestdate" value="<?php echo $value['servicer_requestdate']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="servicer_detail" value="<?php echo $value['servicer_detail']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="servicer_contact" value="<?php echo $value['servicer_contact']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="servicer_priority" value="<?php echo $value['servicer_priority']?>"> 
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" <?php if($value['status']=="Complete") {?> checked="checked"<?php } ?> name="current_status" value="Complete">Complete
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" <?php if($value['status']=="Ongoing") {?> checked="checked"<?php } ?> name="current_status" value="Ongoing">Ongoing
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" <?php if($value['status']=="Rejected") {?> checked="checked"<?php } ?> name="current_status" value="Rejected">Rejected
</label>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
    <span>Status</span>
</button>   

<?php 
    echo form_close(); 
?>
Controller page
public function service1()
{                    
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $page_id =$this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->load->model('Login_set');  
    $this->Login_set->add_status();
    $data['s']=$this->Login_set->select2(); 
    $this->load->view('App_stay/pages/hotel1_service.php',$data);
}

Model page

public function add_status() 
{
    this->load->database();
    this->load->helper('url');
    hotel_id=1;
    servicer_name= $this->input->post('servicer_name');
    servicer_email= $this->input->post('servicer_email'); 
    servicer_checkin= $this->input->post('servicer_checkin');
    servicer_checkout= $this->input->post('servicer_checkout');
    servicer_requestdate= $this->input->post('servicer_requestdate');
    servicer_detail= $this->input->post('servicer_detail');
    servicer_contact= $this->input->post('servicer_contact');
    servicer_priority= $this->input->post('servicer_priority');
    status= $this->input->post('status');
    service_id= $this->input->post('servicer_id');
    data=array('hotel_id'=>$hotel_id,'servicer_name'=>$servicer_name,'servicer_email'=>$servicer_email,'servicer_checkin'=>$servicer_checkin,'servicer_checkout'=>$servicer_checkout,'servicer_requestdate'=>$servicer_requestdate,'servicer_detail'=>$servicer_detail,'servicer_contact'=>$servicer_contact,'servicer_priority'=>$servicer_priority,'status'=>$status);
    this->db->where('service_id',$service_id);
    this->db->update('service_hotel1',$data);            
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing inputs to the model but they are getting passed to the controller function.. please update

Controller:

```
public function service1()
{
    /** you are posting the form to this function and not to the model.
    *   which is why all input->post must be here
    */
    $servicer_name       = $this->input->post('servicer_name');
    $servicer_email      = $this->input->post('servicer_email');
    $servicer_checkin    = $this->input->post('servicer_checkin');
    $servicer_checkout   = $this->input->post('servicer_checkout');
    $servicer_requestdate= $this->input->post('servicer_requestdate');
    $servicer_detail     = $this->input->post('servicer_detail');
    $servicer_contact    = $this->input->post('servicer_contact');
    $servicer_priority   = $this->input->post('servicer_priority');
    $status              = $this->input->post('status');
    $service_id          = $this->input->post('servicer_id');


    $this->load->helper('url');
    $page_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->load->model('Login_set');
    $this->Login_set->add_status($servicer_name, $servicer_email, $servicer_checkin, $servicer_checkout, $servicer_requestdate, $servicer_detail, $servicer_contact, $servicer_priority, $status, $service_id);
    $data['s'] = $this->Login_set->select2();
    $this->load->view('App_stay/pages/hotel1_service',$data); //also view must be loaded without .php so $this->load->view('App_stay/pages/hotel1_service',$data);
}
```

Model:

```
public function add_status($servicer_name, $servicer_email, $servicer_checkin, $servicer_checkout, $servicer_requestdate, $servicer_detail, $servicer_contact, $servicer_priority, $status, $service_id)
{
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $hotel_id =1 ;
    $data = array(
        'hotel_id'             => $hotel_id,
        'servicer_name'        => $servicer_name,
        'servicer_email'       => $servicer_email,
        'servicer_checkin'     => $servicer_checkin,
        'servicer_checkout'    => $servicer_checkout,
        'servicer_requestdate' => $servicer_requestdate,
        'servicer_detail'      => $servicer_detail,
        'servicer_contact'     => $servicer_contact,
        'servicer_priority'    => $servicer_priority,
        'status'               => $status
    );

    $this->db->where('service_id',$service_id);
    $this->db->update('service_hotel1',$data);
}
```